# MYSQL return 0 on hourly count

Tags: mysql, coalesce, isnull, hour

I am at a loss of how to accomplish this but have seen online ISNULL() and COALESCE() used to return a zero if the query is null.  I am unsure though how to use it properly though I am intuitively thinking i need to have in a subquery then have ISNULL or COALESCE around that subquery?

The query goes:

```
SELECT HOUR( dateAdded ) AS HOUR , COUNT( DISTINCT remoteAddr, xForwardedFor) AS cnt
FROM Track
WHERE accessMask =  '1iczo'
AND destination =  'lp_include.php'
AND dateAdded
BETWEEN  '2014-05-01'
AND  '2014-05-02'
GROUP BY HOUR
ORDER BY HOUR
```

Some help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I used what @Barmar had suggested but it wasn't returning accurate results.  I used what he provided and also another topic with a similar situation, [Group by should return 0 when grouping by hours. How to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422206/group-by-should-return-0-when-grouping-by-hours-how-to-do-this) .  I actually didn't find this topic till after posting this one, :( unfortunately.  Here is the final code that appears to return accurate results, distinct across two columns with empty data being returned as 0.

```
SELECT a.hour, COALESCE(cnt, 0) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT 0 AS hour
UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 .....
UNION ALL
  SELECT 23) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT remoteAddr, xForwardedFor) AS cnt, HOUR(dateAdded) AS hour
  FROM Track
  WHERE accessMask =  '1iczo'
  AND destination =  'lp_include.php'
  AND dateAdded
  BETWEEN  '2014-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-05-01 23:59:59') AS totals
ON a.hour = totals.hour
```

Fiddle for better reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ab660/7

Thanks again to @Barmar, he really put me in the right direction to get to the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join with a table that contains all the hours. This must be a `LEFT JOIN` so that the results will include hours that have no matches in `Track` table.

```
SELECT allHours.hour, IFNULL(cnt, 0) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT 0 AS hour
      UNION
      SELECT 1
      UNION
      SELECT 2
      UNION
      SELECT 3
      ...
      UNION
      SELECT 23) AS allHours
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT HOUR(dateAdded) AS hour, COUNT(DISTINCT remoteAddr, xForwardedFor) AS cnt
      FROM Track
      WHERE accessMask =  '1iczo'
      AND destination =  'lp_include.php'
      AND dateAdded
      BETWEEN  '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-02') AS totals
ON allHours.hour = totals.hour
```

Comment: Thank you this is setting me up in the right path!  It is not giving the results it should but I am going to mess around with it and see what needs to be adjusted, thanks very much!  Spent the whole day on this one :)

Comment: Note that this is combining data for two days, since `BETWEEN` is inclusive.

Comment: So the row for hour 0 will contain the total for both `2014-05-01 00:xx` and `2014-05-02 00:xx`.

Comment: Hey Barmar, I am still unable to get the query to return accurate results.  I appreciate the help though and will continue to still mess around with it to get it working properly, thanks again!

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data in the Track table?

Comment: Hey Barmar, I got it working, so awesome!  I used what you gave me above and slowly worked in changes to make it function.  Here is a SQL fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ab660/7 .  Again thanks so much, this helped me a ton and got me learning more about MySQL then previous!

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that you have *some* data for every hour, you can move the conditional part into the `select`:

```
SELECT HOUR(dateAdded) AS HOUR ,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN accessMask =  '1iczo' AND destination =  'lp_include.php'
                      THEN CONCAT(remoteAddr, ',', xForwardedFor)
             END) AS cnt
FROM Track
WHERE dateAdded BETWEEN  '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-02'
GROUP BY HOUR
ORDER BY HOUR;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it is not the case the there is data every hour so this case wont work.  I  was thinking about trying to wrap a IFNULL or COALESCE function around the count portion but was to no avail in return a 0 for that hour.  The reason why I need it in this format is because it will be used in a graph and do not want to use php to add those zeros.  Thanks for the help though, very much appreciated!